# The link for downloading a pdf file in this page is not working, where's the bug?

Tags: pdf, download

This is the webpage. It has a list of commitments and a link at the end so that the user may download a pdf with the list of commitments that he/she has ticked the checkbox of. Could you please check this code and help me identify what is wrong in it? By the way, it is published on Google Sites.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
```

//Formatting

```
<style>
    body {
        background-color: #000;
        color: #fff;
    }
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .commitment {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .commit-checkbox {
        margin-right: 5px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .commit-link {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .commit-link:hover {
        color: #ccc;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Title</h1>
```

//List of commitments

```
<div class="commitment">
    <input type="checkbox" class="commit-checkbox" id="commit1">
    <label for="commit1">Commitment1</label>
</div>
<div class="commitment">
    <input type="checkbox" class="commit-checkbox" id="commit2">
    <label for="commit2">Commitment2</label>
</div>
<div class="commitment">
    <input type="checkbox" class="commit-checkbox" id="commit3">
    <label for="commit3">Commitment3</label>
</div>
<div class="commitment">
    <input type="checkbox" class="commit-checkbox" id="commit4">
    <label for="commit4">Commitment4</label>
</div>
<div class="commitment">
    <input type="checkbox" class="commit-checkbox" id="commit5">
    <label for="commit5">Commitment5</label>
</div>
<div class="commitment">
    <input type="checkbox" class="commit-checkbox" id="commit6">
    <label for="commit6">Commitment6</label>
</div>
<div class="commitment">
    <input type="checkbox" class="commit-checkbox" id="commit7">
    <label for="commit7">Commitment7</label>
</div>
<div class="commitment">
    <input type="checkbox" class="commit-checkbox" id="commit8">
    <label for="commit8">Commitment8</label>
</div>
<div class="commitment">
    <input type="checkbox" class="commit-checkbox" id="commit9">
    <label for="commit9">Commitment9</label>
</div>

<a href="#" class="commit-link">Commit</a>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
```

//script for creating the pdf for download

```
<script>
    const commitLink = document.querySelector('.commit-link');
    const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.commit-checkbox');
    const commitments = [];

    commitLink.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        checkboxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
            if (checkbox.checked) {
                commitments.push(checkbox.id);
            }
        });

        const doc = new jsPDF();
        for (const commitment of commitments) {
            doc.text(commitment + "\n", 10, 10);
        }

        doc.save('commitments.pdf');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```